# Snapping to the edge

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I snap a simple window to the screen(desktop) edge?

I've found [this post using a library called Huddled](http://huddledmasses.org/wpf-windows-that-snap-to-screen-edges/), but I can't compile with it.
Is something wrong?

```
<Window x:Class="CMD_Bar.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:huddled="http://schemas.huddledmasses.org/wpf"
    Title="CMD" Height="500" Width="500" Topmost="True" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" FontSize="12">

<huddled:Native.Behaviors>
    <huddled:SnapToBehavior SnapDistance="20" />
</huddled:Native.Behaviors>

<Grid>       
    <Label Content="Something" />
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:**
Here are the error messages:

> The tag 'Native.Behaviors' does not exist in XML namespace 
>   'http://schemas.huddledmasses.org/wpf'. Line 9 Position 6
>
> The type 'huddled:SnapToBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.    D:\CMD-Bar\CMD-Bar\MainWindow.xaml

Comment: I hope somebody will tell. I've just found it here: http://huddledmasses.org/wpf-windows-that-snap-to-screen-edges/.

Comment: I'm guessing "stg" is short for "something".  Took a few minutes to figure out, though.  And if something isn't compiling, please include the error message in the question.  If you make the question clear enough, it can be re-opened.